# How to disassemble a simple door knob?

Tags: doors, lock, hardware

I'm trying to fix [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtAYr2uXTMo) wobbly knob. I removed the set screws you see in the video on both sides of the door, but I'm still not able to pull the knob off. It doesn't give even 1/32". Is there another mechanism by which this knob is held together?

[image]

Comment: Just a wild guess, so not posting as an answer. But check the other side for another setscrew, and also see if you can "unscrew" the knob after taking setscrews out, instead of pulling off.

Comment: @PhilippNagel. Removed both set screws. Wasn't able to "unscrew" either knob.

Comment: Have your tried removing  all the screws that hold the rest of the assemble to the door, or to the assembly on the side of the door, to see if it all comes apart.  Are the two holes i see, above and below the knob, screws?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a picture of an antique doorknob assembly. As @PhilippNagel commented, these should screw off once you remove the setscrew. If it's not unscrewing, double-check the other doorknob and remove a setscrew from that one, then hold both knobs and unscrew. One of them should come off.

[image]